# Google Slide API-How do i duplicate a slide several times and creating a unique object id each time

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-slides-api

In general i want people to put some data into a google sheet and provide a button, which takes the data and automatically fills a prefabricated google slide. I have chosen the approach to duplicate a master slide and then replacing individual text modulars with the data. Is there a better approach for my goal?

This is the Master-Slide

[image: Master-Slide]

This is the code i use for the duplication, but it is only able to duplicate the master slide once, because the objectId it creates, is always the same: "copiedSlide_001". I have tried to use a random integer for the objectId, but i dont get it to work. Also, i guess the name has to be predictable to be used in the next step. (importing the data into newly copied slide).

```
function duplicateSlide() {  

    var presentationId = "1XLtOv7FHWwv6R2QEZF_LEhF7twXTlY3IbvsVDKxdDtc";
    var pageId = "g75e5d89173_0_0"
    var requests = [{

      "duplicateObject": {
        "objectId": pageId,
        "objectIds": {
          "g75e5d89173_0_0": "copiedSlide_001",

        }
      }
    } ]Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, presentationId);
    }
```

How do i get the duplication process to work in my favor?

I would appreciate any help highly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to copy the master slide several times in Google Slides.
- You want to give the unique object ID for each copied slide like `copiedSlide_001`.

  - You are required to know the object ID of the copied slide before copying it.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification point:

- In this modification, it requests several DuplicateObjectRequest using the method of batchUpdate.

#### Modified script:

Before you run the script, please enable Slides API at Advanced Google services.

```
function duplicateSlide() {
  var presentationId = "1XLtOv7FHWwv6R2QEZF_LEhF7twXTlY3IbvsVDKxdDtc"; // Please set the Slides ID.
  var pageId = "g75e5d89173_0_0"; // Please set the page ID of the source slide.
  var newIDs = ["copiedSlide_001", "copiedSlide_002", "copiedSlide_003"]; // Please set the unique ID here.

  var requests = newIDs.reverse().map(function(id) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[pageId] = id;
    return {duplicateObject: {objectId: pageId, objectIds: obj}};
  });
//  requests.push({deleteObject: {objectId: pageId}});
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, presentationId);
}
```

- When you run the script, as a test case, the source slide is copied 3 times. And each object ID is "copiedSlide_001", "copiedSlide_002" and "copiedSlide_003", respectively.

  - The page IDs of 2nd, 3rd and 4th pages are "copiedSlide_001", "copiedSlide_002" and "copiedSlide_003", respectively.
- If you use `requests.push({deleteObject: {objectId: pageId}});`, after the copy was finished, the 1st page, which is the source slide, is deleted. But I'm not sure whether this is the result you want. So I put it in the script as a comment.

#### References:

- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [DuplicateObjectRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#duplicateobjectrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Awesome! Thats more than sufficient for an answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Julian Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing a brief and well-explained answer @Tanaike, the code did the job very well. I am pretty sure many python developers might be struggling with this as well, so I would just like to share your code translated into python language.

I hope this helps and save someone's time.

```py
import json
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# authenticating and creating service obj
creds = json.load(open('credentials.json', 'r'))
credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(info=creds)
service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

def duplicate_slide():
    presentation_id = "1XLtOv7FHWwv6R2QEZF_LEhF7twXTlY3IbvsVDKxdDtc" 
    page_id = "g75e5d89173_0_0"  # id of page you want to duplicate
    new_ids = ["copiedSlide_001", "copiedSlide_002", "copiedSlide_003"]

    # requests
    requests = []
    for id in new_ids[::-1]:
        obj = {page_id: id}
        requests.append({'duplicateObject': {'objectId': page_id, 'objectIds': obj}})

    # Uncomment the following line if you want to delete the original slide
    # requests.append({'deleteObject': {'objectId': page_id}})

    service.presentations().batchUpdate(presentationId=presentation_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()

duplicate_slide()
```

@credit: Tanaike