# Duplicating a slide several times - Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Trying to duplicate 3 (could be more, depending on the presentation) slides multiple times.

After searching have found a close result:
[Google Slide API-How do i duplicate a slide several times and creating a unique object id each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284060/google-slide-api-how-do-i-duplicate-a-slide-several-times-and-creating-a-unique),
however does not allow for a third slide.

Code so far is as follows:

```
function duplicateSlide() {
  var presentationId = "1J14grlx5pMrcsglMvmDVB22vTf89Qt0JUaq394Rltfc"; // Please set the Slides ID.
  var pageId1 = "g1399daed6c0_0_89"; // Please set the page ID of the source slide.
  var pageId2 = "g1399daed6c0_0_9"; // Please set the page ID of the source slide.
  var pageId3 = "g1399daed6c0_0_15"; // Please set the page ID of the source slide.
  
  
  var newID1 = ["First_1", "First_2", "First_3", "First_4"]; // Please set the unique ID here."
  var newID2 = ["Second_1A", "Second_2B", "Second_3C", "Second_4D"]; // Please set the unique ID here."
  var newID3 = ["Third_1A1", "Third_2B2", "Third_3C3", "Third_4D4"]; // Please set the unique ID here."

  var requests = newID1.reverse().map(function(id) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[pageId1] = id;
    return {duplicateObject: {objectId: pageId1, objectIds: obj}};
  });
  var requests = newID2.reverse().map(function(id) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[pageId2] = id;
    return {duplicateObject: {objectId: pageId2, objectIds: obj}};
  });
  var requests = newID3.reverse().map(function(id) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[pageId3] = id;
    return {duplicateObject: {objectId: pageId3 , objectIds: obj}};
  });
//  requests.push({deleteObject: {objectId: pageId}});
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, presentationId);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, only 3rd `requests` is used. Because the 1st `requests` is overwritten by 2nd `requests`, and the 2nd `requests` is overwritten by 3rd `requests`. If you want to include all requests, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var requests = newID1.reverse().map(function(id) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[pageId1] = id;
  return {duplicateObject: {objectId: pageId1, objectIds: obj}};
});
var requests = newID2.reverse().map(function(id) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[pageId2] = id;
  return {duplicateObject: {objectId: pageId2, objectIds: obj}};
});
var requests = newID3.reverse().map(function(id) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[pageId3] = id;
  return {duplicateObject: {objectId: pageId3 , objectIds: obj}};
});
```

#### To:

```
var requests1 = newID1.reverse().map(function (id) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[pageId1] = id;
  return { duplicateObject: { objectId: pageId1, objectIds: obj } };
});
var requests2 = newID2.reverse().map(function (id) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[pageId2] = id;
  return { duplicateObject: { objectId: pageId2, objectIds: obj } };
});
var requests3 = newID3.reverse().map(function (id) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[pageId3] = id;
  return { duplicateObject: { objectId: pageId3, objectIds: obj } };
});
var requests = [...requests1, ...requests2, ...requests3];
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply @Tanaike, your reply was what I was looking for.

Comment: @SCTJ Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.